# How can I make a embed help slash command using pycord?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

how can I make the embed help command that uses slash commands?

[like this help command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32OBV.png)

i have only non slash command:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx, args=None):
    help_embed = discord.Embed(title="My Bot's Help!")
    command_names_list = [x.name for x in bot.commands]
    if not args:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="List of supported commands:",
            value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,x in enumerate(bot.commands)]),
            inline=False
        )
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Details",
            value="Type `.help <command name>` for more details about each command.",
            inline=False
        )

    elif args in command_names_list:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name=args,
            value=bot.get_command(args).help
        )
    else:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Oh, no!",
            value="I didn't find command :("
        )
    await ctx.send(embed=help_embed)
```

Comment: it may need to turn off original help - `Bot(command_prefix='/', help_command=None)`

Comment: pycord @bot.slash_command hasn't default help command

Comment: `pycord` changes problem :) So I reopen question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `pycord` as it is shown in the tags of the post.

The function taken as a decorator isn't `bot.command()` anymore, for a slash command but `bot.slash_command()`

It can takes as parameter a `name`, that will be displayed when typing the command on discord, a `description`, to provide details about the command, and for the general case, all the paramters taken by `@bot.command()`

Your script will look like this:

```
import discord
from discord import Option
bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command(name="help", description="This is a test")
async def help(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
       args: discord.Option(discord.SlashCommandOptionType.string, "args", required=False, default=None)):
        help_embed = discord.Embed(title="My Bot's Help!")
        command_names_list = [x.name for x in bot.commands]
    if not args:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="List of supported commands:",
            value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,x in enumerate(bot.commands)]),
            inline=False
        )
        help_embed.add_field(
        name="Details",
        value="Type `.help <command name>` for more details about each command.",
        inline=False
    )

    elif args in command_names_list:
        help_embed.add_field(
        name=args,
        value=bot.get_command(args).description
    )
    else:
        help_embed.add_field(
        name="Oh, no!",
        value="I didn't find command :("
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=help_embed)

bot.run("YOUR TOKEN")
```

See: `https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=slash_command#discord.Bot.slash_command`

Comment: description of command doesn't work (I have description="" in all commands)

Comment: You have to set a description for each of your command, as I did (the parameters of the decorator).